# Storyboard corrupted

Tags: xamarin

I've experienced a strange problem today. I was working on my iOS app in xamarinstudio. A modification had to be made in one of my viewcontrollers, so i opened up my storyboard to see that most of my viewcontrollers were missing! The connection between viewcontrollers was still there, in fact, my app still works, but most viewcontrollers are missing. When you open the .storyboard file in a texteditor, you can clearly see that the missing viewcontrollers all have their width & height properties set to 0! This happened suddenly, without any warning. I can't even remember exactly when this happened, because i didn't open my storyboard file right away. The only two things i did differently that day is execute the updates for Xamarin studio, mono, xCode, the emulator & iOS and i modified a .xib, so i had to open xCode. Here is a screenshot of what my storyboards looks like now:

[image]

Has anybody encountered something similar? And how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening Storyboard as code (2 finger tap) and look around to see if there are any view controllers present. Maybe the size was corrupted to zero? You can edit that inside storyboard.